# How to get the schema of a MongoDB database with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, schema, mongoid

I adopted a project that includes MongoDB and Mongoid. I liked the way you can check out the schema design of the database in the `schema.rb` with ActiveRecord or with the Annotate gem. How can I visually see the schema design of MongoDB? Are there any gems or tricks available similar to Annotate or schema.rb for MongoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheme should be based on your models. To see the schema in a project that uses Mongoid, look at the relationships between your model classes. Keywords like `has_many` and `embeds_one` are Mongoid commands defining the relationships between your documents. You won't find anything like `schema.rb`, because the database isn't as "static" as a traditional relational database -- you could have two documents in the same collection with different properties.

Another option would be to use software to browse the database. I use MongoHub on Mac. This will give you a nice graphical view of your data.

Comment: Yeah I know how MongoDB works and all that, didn't know about MongoHub though. Will check that out and if it works I'll give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Genghis](https://github.com/bobthecow/genghis). It's great, super easy to install, consistently updated, and exactly what I was looking for.